# Finding the most frequent element in a list excluding a certain character

Tags: python, list

I need to run a function that returns the most frequent element in a list except for a certain character, in this case the character `'W'`.

For example, I have a list

```
n = ['W', 3, 'W', 1, 'W', 3, 2, 2, 3, 2]
```

How would I get an output of `2` or `3` instead of `'W'`, which is what `statistics.mode(n)` is currently giving me?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why is `2` not `3` here?  Can you explain?  Because `{'W': 3, 3: 3, 2: 3, 1: 1})` Since both numbers are appearing same times.

Comment: @Ender I didn't downvote but questions that don't show an attempt to solve the problem, ideally with code, will often get downvoted

Comment: I tried running ``statistics.mode()``... Thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: I did offer an answer using collections.Counter but it was apparently not up to standard so I deleted it

Comment: Could you put it here? I would appreciate the answer being put here for the benefit of other users even if it is not up to standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
statistics.mode([v for v in n if v != 'W'])
```

instead. For furter details on list comprehensions, check out [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) link.

Comment: You can also apply [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter): `statistics.mode(filter('W'.__ne__, n))`.

Comment: Could you explain what ``filter()`` and ``__ne__`` are?

Comment: @Ender, in docs of [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) you could read next: *"Construct an iterator from those elements of **iterable** (second argument) for which **function** (first argument) returns true"*. So we need to pass a callable which will return `False` if item have to be filtered. In Python Data Model you can find that [`object.__ne__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) is function which called by `a != b` expression. So when we pass `'W'.__ne__` to filter it will check every item of iterable to not equal `'W'`.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan, you might need to explain a little bit about how this works or add outside links/references (see comment in below answer), but thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Enderman You are welcome, but honestly, who does not understand what `v for v in n if v != 'W'` means? The syntactic sugar makes this bit to be almost in plain English.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan I guess new users, random people on the internet, and Python beginners. Maybe just add a Stack Overflow question link that explains these types of list comprehensions?

Comment: @Enderman Gotcha Mr. Enderman.

Answer (score -1):

```py
thisdict = {
}

n = ["W", 3, "W", 1, "W", 3, 2, 2, 3, 2]

for i in n:

  if i in thisdict.keys():

    thisdict[i] = thisdict[i] + 1

  else:

    if (i == "W"):
      continue

    thisdict[i] =  1

max = 0
maxKey = None

for key in thisdict.keys():

    if( thisdict[key] >= max ):

    max = thisdict[key]

    maxKey = key

print("Element Occurred Max Number of Times-->", maxKey)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).